# Docker can't see some files?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-registry

I want to create a docker registry on my server using this docker-compose.yaml file :

```
version: '3'
services:
  registry:
    restart: always
    image: registry:2
    ports:
      - 5000:5000

    volumes:
      - /home/ubuntu/registry/volumes/data:/var/lib/registry
      - /home/ubuntu/registry/volumes/certs:/certs
      - /home/ubuntu/registry/volumes/auth:/auth
    environment:
      REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE: /home/ubuntu/registry/certs/domain.crt
      REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY: /home/ubuntu/registry/certs/domain.key
      REGISTRY_AUTH: htpasswd
      REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH: /home/ubuntu/registry/auth/htpasswd
      REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM: Registry Realm
```

I am running
 ''' 
docker-compose up
 ''' 
but this error occurs.

```
registry_1  | time="2019-08-03T21:17:38.938127498Z" level=fatal msg="open /home/ubuntu/registry/certs/domain.crt: no such file or directory"
```

I am sure those files exist, do you have any idea?

Comment: They exist on the host, not in the container.

Comment: I know, but I think this container should read them from the host, right?

Comment: If you `docker-compose run registry sh` and poke around, you should see directories `/certs` and `/auth` with the content from the host, but they will not be the host-specific path names.  You should change the environment variables to match the paths inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

```
volumes:
  - /home/ubuntu/registry/volumes/certs:/certs
```

Here you are saying to use the HOST path `/home/ubuntu/registry/volumes/certs` and make it available as `/certs` inside the CONTAINER. So perhaps you want to change the path on the container side to match the host path, or change the environment variables to reflect the actual container paths.

Also note that you have used `/home/ubuntu/registry/volumes/certs` in one location and `/home/ubuntu/registry/certs` (without "volumes") in another, which I assume might need to be fixed up as well.